# Rails 3 Jquery Ajax how to insert a new element in the propper place

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a list of tasks that sorted by the due date. When I create a new task it gets appended to the list.

Problem: I really want the new task to appear in the right place in the list of tasks.

When I make a task for monday, I want it to get inserted after the other monday tasks and not get appended to the end of the list.

I've tried to add a data-due attribute to the tasks and loop trough the values.

But I find this soloution to complex.

Do you know a simpler soloution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set each of the list items to have an html id property

```
<li id="task_123">
```

you can figure out which record to insert before / after using rails, and then use jquery to just insert at the correct place.

Comment: Yeah. I've tried this to. But, it seems to put to much strain on both server and client for such a small task. Perhaps there is no easy way to do this. Thanks for answering!

Comment: this shouldn't be a big strain on the server. Since you're loading each record anyways from the db with rails, it isn't a lot more work to just take the id from each of the records you're already loading and adding an html id element. Also, this shouldn't be more strain on the client at all.